# Oracle endeca cas service not starting

Tags: endeca

I am a newbie to endeca. When I try to run the CAS service from the bin directory of CAS/3.0.2 . Then I can't access CAS wsdl at the url http://localhost:8500/cas/wsdl? . I don't know at which port it is running. Or It is taking too much time to start up? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong URL.

The `wsdl` is available on http://localhost:8500/cas/?wsdl. If you still can't access it check in your `<CAS_HOME>\workspace\logs\cas-service.log` if it started up correctly.

Some info, specifically for your version, is available [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29578_01/webhelp/cas_dev/src/tcasd_starting_cas_service_from_cmd.html)